# Apt-mirror monitoring how to?

Tags: repository, monitoring

We have created a local Ubuntu repository using apt-mirror and i must say it has been awesome.
But now one issue that we are facing is that we need to monitor which version of Ubuntu is being accessed more for packages, which packages are being downloaded more and all sort of things.
It would be great if someone could show us the way or just tell us how could we set up a monitoring for apt-mirror.

Answer (score 1):

You would just need to ensure that you have the right amount of logging setup for Apache2 and then just grep the logs for the information that you want. You would have to know the directory path for the given Ubuntu version. Here's some details for how to customize Apache logging:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/logs.html